# Get data from table on post

Tags: php, post, html-table

I have a function that creates a list of users in a form dynamically

```
  public function createMemberListObject($name, $id, $socialSecurity)
{
    return '
    <form method="post">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkthis" /></td>
    <td>' . $name . '</td>
    <td>' . $id . '</td>
    <td>' . $socialSecurity . '</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
    <input  class="btn btn-primary btn-xs " type="submit" name="' . self::$edit . '" value="edit" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <input  class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="submit" name="' . self::$delete . '" value="delete" />
    </td>
</tr>
</form>
    ';
}
```

this creates a table depending on how many users in the database.

The problem is how do I get access to the name on the specific table when I post with "self::edit"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden input:

```
public function createMemberListObject($name, $id, $socialSecurity)
{
    return '
    <form method="post">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkthis" /></td>
    <td>' . $name . '</td>
    <td>' . $id . '</td>
    <td>' . $socialSecurity . '</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="' . $name . '">
    <input  class="btn btn-primary btn-xs " type="submit" name="' . self::$edit . '" value="edit" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <input  class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="submit" name="' . self::$delete . '" value="delete" />
    </td>
</tr>
</form>
    ';
}
```

You access this just like any other input, with `$_POST['name']`.

Comment: And how do I access it?

Comment: `$_POST['name']` just like any other input.

Comment: Haha aah right! Im stupid! Thank you so much! It worked!